# Rails 3.1 Assets Problem in Dev mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I am developing a rails 3.1 application.

I put 7 images in app/assets/images//.

A page is supposed to show the 7 images. But my browser doesn't display all the images.  Some images are not displayed randomly. Sometimes #1, 2, 3 images are not displayed and other times #6,7 images are not displayed.

If I type the image address in the address field, the image displays well.

This only happened in dev mode. Production mode displays them well.

Has anybody experienced the same thing?

Thanks.

Sam

Comment: Are you calling images from view or css ?

Comment: I am calling images from view using image_tag. The weird thing is that the generated image url doesn't have cache buster (?123945720578).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can sometimes happen if Sprockets' local cache gets corrupted or saves a blank image. Try deleting the tmp/cache/assets folder and restarting your app. Do a forced refresh on the browser to to ensure all images are refetched.

The cache-buster query string is not used in 3.1. This has been replaced with a fingerprinting system (see the [asset pipeline guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) for more).

If this is an upgraded app, check the settings in your environment files (from the guide) to make sure all the options are set correctly for each mode. Some combinations of setting can cause weird stuff to happen with images.

Answer (score 1):

What webserver are you using?

I've encountered the same when using passenger. Found some posts advising to switch to thin, which solved the issue.

Comment: I use Pow on my macbook pro development machine. Hmmm

Comment: Based on issues on the Rails tracker during the 3.1 RC phase, the 'switch to thin works' could be a symptom of having x-sendfile headers turned on or set for Apache (the configs are different). See the guides for more info.